# with firewalld is it possible to use an invert ipset as source?

Tags: fedora, firewalld, ipset

with firewalld  I can make a rule like this: (`note the invert="True"`)

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.100.0/24" invert="True" drop'
```

and I can specify that for certain sources I need them treated as part of a zone  with this:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external  --add-source=ipset:knowns
```

Is it possible to invert this and say make sure any ip that is not in the ipset is treated as a part of another specified zone?
I have had a look at the man page, and I can not find any indication whether this is possible.

Comment: hi, looks like only `ipset` command supports the option `nomatch` while adding entries. firewall-cmd does not allow to add entries using this option. IMHO this is the feature you (and me) would like to have, so we could build zones/ipsets to exclude certain ip ranges (e.g. countries) by only adding those "bad" ranges.

Answer (score 1):

you can mimic this behavior by creating an ipset (using firewall-cmd) containing all "bad" IP adresses/ranges.
you then add a firewalld zone with this ipset as source only.

`# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=axisofevil --add-source=ipset:roguenations`

all traffic with sources of the ipset "roguenations" will have access to all services of the zone "axisofevil". if you don't allow any services at all, no service will be available to those clients.

don't forget to add another zone of type inet6 containing all "bad" IPv6 adresses/ranges.

`# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=roguenations6 --type=hash:net --family=inet6`

hint: you can use entire geo IP databases from e.g. https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker in CIDR format to be added to the ipset (using firewall-cmd --new-ipset-from-file *or* --add-entries-from-file .. :)

I suggest to disable "AllowZoneDrifting" which defaults to on.

HTH